# Spring Scheduled первый запуск с cron

Tags: spring, scheduler

В моем приложении необходимо, чтобы оно запускалось два раза в день.

Сделал так

> @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 8,18 * * *", zone = "Europe/Moscow")

Все работает, но приложение простаивает и ожидает пока наступит время для выполнения задачи.
В моем примере 8 утра и 6 вечера

Вопрос, как сделать так чтобы при первом запуске автоматически запускались определенные методы сбора данных (парсинг с сайта) без ожидания пока наступит время по cron, а после уже дальше по расписанию работало.

Comment: В общем случае можно пометить метод аннотацией `@PostConstruct`, но есть нюансы: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401536/3212712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большое спасибо [ЮриюСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1)

@PostConstruct не совсем подходит под мою задачу, но перейдя по его [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401536/3212712)
Внизу нашелся ответ на мой вопрос, я добавил аннотацию к методу запуска задачи (будет прикреплен ниже) и все прекрасно работает.

> @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)

```
@Component
class StartupHousekeeper {

    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void contextRefreshedEvent() {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```